# Как фиксировать боковое меню при прокрутке content?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Как фиксировать боковое меню (во время прокрутки `content`) на Bootstrap, так же как это реализовано у фильтра на сайте [Apple](http://www.apple.com/shop/mac/mac-accessories/displays-mounts)?

Comment: На сайте Bootstrap сделано получше чем на сайте Apple, а реализовать это можно с помощью bootstrap affix: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Comment: подписываешься на скролл окна, и если `scrollTop > ` твоего значения (от которого что-то должно фиксироваться), блок даешь например `position: fixed`

Comment: @TheMaker не надо заниматься вандализмом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот хороший пример - http://www.bootply.com/90936

Ну если вам копия как у apple нужна вот сам скрипт - http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4973/store.apple.com/shop/rs-web/rel/category-flex.js

Comment: Не внимательно задание читаешь. Требуется после определенного расстояния фиксировать блок, а не изначально

Comment: Если считаете что ваш пример подходит, добавьте его в ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.